# Is it possible to validate a input field and set error messages from typescript file instead of HTML file: Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am new to angular ,may be my question is not worthless but I need to learn these basic things .Hope here I can find a solution for my question.

As of now I have validated a Input Field which get the First Name of a user and it's working fine.

My question is why I have all these validations and error messages in my **html** file.

If it is possible please tell me how to do that or else correct me where my understanding wrong .

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-sm-6">
                        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput minlength="4" pattern="^[a-z]*$" maxlength="15" [formControl]="fName" required>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="fName.errors?.required">Please fill out this field</mat-error>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="fName.errors&&fName.errors?.minlength">Required minimum 4 characters</mat-error>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="fName.errors&&fName.errors.pattern">Enter only alphabets</mat-error>
                      </mat-form-field>
```

TypeScript:

```
fName = new FormControl();
```

It's working fine.But I need to know that the same thing is possible to do from TYPESCRIPT file.

Sorry ,if my question is wasting your valuable minutes.

Comment: dude,may I know the reason of down voting ,which will helpful for me in future post.

Comment: I am confused with ``My question is why I have all these validations and error messages in my **typescript** file.` . Do you mean to say it as **html** file ? Because you are also saying `.But I need to know that the same thing is possible to do from TYPESCRIPT file.` No idea abt downvote bro

Comment: Yes off course because I have all these code in my app.component.html file @ShashankVivek

Comment: its not abt offcourse, its about correcting your question.Lemme do that for you

Comment: oh,sorry bro it's a typo ...Can you give me the solution for my question .@ShashankVivek

Comment: working on it will tell you bro....@ShashankVivek

Comment: did my answer helped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the changes of a form using

```
myForm: FormGroup;

this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(()=> { 
    // You can listen to changes here.
    // assign proper msg in this.fnameErrorMsg for invalid fname
})
```

and you can create custom error messages in some variable like `{{fnameErrorMsg}}`

You can checkout a sample reactive form that I have created [over my git profile](https://github.com/shashankvivek/Angular4/tree/master/Reactive_creature_form/src/app) for more. Although, I have not implemented what you are looking for. But it can help you with that form

```
<mat-error *ngIf="!myForm.controls['fName'].valid">{{fnameErrorMsg}}</mat-error>
```